# Traverse through two dimensional array with variable sized strings in C

Tags: c

What am I doing wrong here? The first one works like a charm the second one crashes.

```
char *t[3][4] = {
  {"one", "two", "three", "Four"},
  {"Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"},
  {"Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve"}
};
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
  for (j=0;j<4;j++) {
    printf("%s\n",t[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Same array just want to use in function:

```
foo(t, 3, 4);

char **foo(char **t, int row, int col) {
  int i,j;
  for (i=0;i<row;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<col;j++) {
      printf("%s\n",t[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 8 second(s));

Comment: `char **foo(char **t, int row, int col)` --> `void foo(int row, int col, char *t[row][col]) (call `foo(3, 4, t);`)
`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: You don't even have to specify 'row' there since C's row major indexing will automatically take care of the first dimension, if the second is passed to it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to pass `char ***` (which would be incorrect as a 2D array of `char *` is not a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to-char) or just thought a `char **` would refer to an array of `char *` regardless of the number of dimensions (also not right, but a different misunderstanding)...

Comment: @Shiva It is not necessary, but I think that descriptive.

Comment: Did the compiler not warn you about type mismatches?  It should have done.  Fundamentally, the type of `t` in the argument list of `foo` does not match the type of `t`, the array.  When I compiled your code, I got errors (because I convert warnings to errors with `-Werror`) like: `asp19.c:22:9: error: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]` identifying the line `foo(t, 3, 4);`
and observing `asp19.c:3:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)[4]’` referring to `void foo(char **t, int row, int col);`

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with pointers is cumbersome, especially with string matrices. It's best to write your function in such a way that the compiler clearly knows what's being passed to it.

Change your function signature to `void foo(int row, int col, char* t[][col]) { ... }`, and correspondingly, call your function as `foo(3, 4, t);`. You're clearly telling the compiler what's being passed.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code witch worked with `char **foo(char **t, int row, int col)`. The problem was that i had a ** array with a pointer to its beginning, and you cant traverse it like a simple 2d array like t[i][j]. But you can use i*col to reach the row you want, and the j is the locating the j-th element in i-th row.
Extra note that the size of the containing strings doesnt matter because you have addresses in the array . Thanks for the helpful comments witch led me to the correct answer.

```
for (i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
        printf("%s",*(t+i*col+j)); 
        }
    }
```